# Getting this error when starting a react native app for iphone

Tags: iphone, react-native, expo

iOS Bundling failed 523ms
error: node_modules/expo-router/_ctx.ios.tsx: node_modules/expo-router/_ctx.ios.tsx:Invalid call at line 6: // @ts-expect-error
process.env.EXPO_ROUTER_IMPORT_MODE_IOS
Fourth argument of `require.context` should be an optional string "mode" denoting how the modules will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve this issue by adding `expo-router/babel` to plugins in the project babel config. I also needed to make a new EAS dev client build.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on expo SDK 50 and using expo-router v3 you should NOT include `expo-router/babel` in babel.config. If you're using tamagui with expo router v3 both on SDK 50 you should remove the `transform-inline-environment-variables` from babel.config as its messing with the `EXPO_ROUTER_APP_ROOT` ENV.

Other workarround is to manually set the APP_ROOT var on top of your babel.config with
`process.env.EXPO_ROUTER_APP_ROOT = '../../src/app';`

reference:

- https://github.com/expo/router/issues/41
- https://github.com/tamagui/tamagui/issues/2044